# How to achieve sequential blocking behavior in multithread application?

Tags: c#, multithreading, plc

I'm writing an application that should simulate the behavior of a PLC. This means I have to run several threads making sure only one thread at a time is active and all others are suspended.
For example:

- thread 1 repeats every 130ms and blocks all other threads. The effective runtime is 30ms and the remaining 100ms before the thread restarts can be used by other threads.
- thread 2 repeats every 300ms and blocks all threads except for thread 1. The effective runtime is 50ms (the remaining 250ms can be used by other threads). Thread 2 is paused until thread 1 has finished executing code (the remaining 100ms of thread 1) and once thread 1 is asleep it resumes from where it has been paused
- thread 3 repeats every 1000ms. The effective runtime is 100ms. This thread continues execution only if all other threads are suspended.

The highest priority is to complete the tasks before they are called again, otherwise I have to react, therefore a thread that should be blocked should not run until a certain point, otherwise multicore processing would elaborate the code and only wait to pass the results.

I read several posts and learned that Thread.suspend is not recomended and semaphore or monitor operations mean that the code is executed until a specific and fixed point in the code while I have to pause the threads exactly where the execution has arrived when an other thread (with higher "priority") is called.

I also looked at the priority setting but it doesn't seem to be 100% relevant since the system can override priorities.

Is there a correct or at least solid way to code the blocking mechanism?

Comment: You probably want a real-time application, where high-priority thread *immediately* and *unconditionally* preemts low-priority one, and timing is critical. Windows itself is not suitable for *hard real-time applications*. Is your application is performance-critical? If it is not, you can simulate *immediate preemtion* by inserting conditional waits in low-priority threads.

Comment: Real time would be nice, but neither Windows nor C# are the way to go there. The requested performance is easily achiveable, i'm just stuck in the suspending mechanism. I have to make sure that higher priority tasks block lower priority task wherever they are in the code sequence and unblocking a task has to continue execution from where it has paused.

Comment: As performance is not an issue, you can emulate real-time priority and immediate preemtion by inserting something like `SleepIfNeeded();` call in your threads code. This call should wait in case higher-priority thread is executed. It is not needed to insert this call after every line of code, e.g., you can use it only before modification of public(observable) data. Care to use this call inside critical sections, as it can cause deadlock(because of *priority inversion*).

Comment: In this case the code runs on until a certain point. It solves my problems with variable updates but it means that multiple thread will run at the same time. My application is time sensitive, meaning that I need to execute the code as a sequence otherwise it could happen that a thread would not finish in its predetermined runtime because of the interraction with other threads, but beeing run simultaneously the code has already been elaborated and therefore I will never know.

Comment: I have edited the question to be more specific about the time sensitive aspect.

Comment: I don't think you need multiple threads at all.  A PLC runs a simple, sequential loop.  Read inputs, solve ladder (sequentially), write outputs, repeat.  This seems overly complicated...

Comment: A PLC runs multiple parallel tasks (OBs) wich can or be different programs at all or simply functions of a single program with lesser priority (such as graphics or communication). The problem is that PLC's don't are really multitasking but execute tasks time based or called by interrupt and these conditions make it hard to simulate a PLC on a PC. The time a single program block takes to be executed can vary the output heavily if meanwhile the task is interrupted in the wrong way.

Comment: (for example: task 1 has a timeout control for a certain variable that task 2 controls. If the threads are not executed correctly the simulation would cause the timeout to react while the real PLC wouldn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to burden yourself with `Thread`s at all. Instead, you can use `Task`s with a prioritised `TaskScheduler` (it's not too hard to write or find by googling).

This makes the code quite easy to write, for example the highest priority thread might be something like:

```
while (!cancellationRequested)
{
  var repeatTask = Task.Delay(130);

  // Do your high priority work      

  await repeatTask;
}
```

Your other tasks will have a similar basic layout, but they will be given a lower priority in the task scheduler (this is usually handled by the task scheduler having a separate queue for each of the task priorities). Once in a while, they can check whether there is a higher priority task, and if so, they can do `await Task.Yield();`. In fact, in your case, it seems like you don't even need real queues - that makes this a lot easier, and even better, allows you to use `Task.Yield` really efficiently.

The end result is that all three of your periodic tasks are efficiently run on just a single thread (or even no thread at all if they're all waiting).

This does rely on coöperative multi-tasking, of course. It's not really possible to handle full blown real-time like pre-emption on Windows - and partial pre-emption solutions tend to be full of problems. If you're in control of most of the time spent in the task (and offload any other work using asynchronous I/O), the coöperative solution is actually far more efficient, and can give you a lot less latency (though it really shouldn't matter much).

Comment: This is interesting. I give it a try. Thanks

Comment: I tried a simple example and noticed that like other methods the execution of a task isn't suspended in wich ever position it is in when a higher priority task is called but finishes until the await function.

Comment: @MaximilianEheim Yes, it's still *coöperative* multi-tasking. There's no way to pre-empt, really. You can asynchronously invoke a thread abort or suspend, but that's a bad idea - the code you're trying to suspend should have a say in when that happens. The key is that if you use the `await`s reasonably throughout the code, it should still give you better latency than pre-emptive multi-tasking - Windows is *not* an environment to write real-time applications (and no, Unix isn't either). Your callback is never going to be called *exactly* each 100 ms.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I don't missunderstand your question :)

One possibility to your problem might be to use a concurrent queue: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=net-6.0)

For example you create a enum to control your state and init the queue:

```
 private ConcurrentQueue<Action> _clientActions ;
     private enum Statuskatalog
      {
           Idle,
           Busy
       };
```

Create a timer to start and create a timerfunktion.

```
Timer _taskTimer = new Timer(ProcessPendingTasks, null, 100, 333);



private void ProcessPendingTasks(object x)
         {
           _status = Statuskatalog.Busy;
             _taskTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
             Action currentTask;
             while( _clientActions.TryDequeue( out currentTask ))
             {
                 var task = new Task(currentTask);
                 task.Start();         
                 task.Wait();
             }

         _status=Statuskatalog.Idle;
         }
```

Now you only have to add your tasks as delegates to the queue:

```
_clientActions.Enqueue(delegate { **Your task** });
            if (_status == Statuskatalog.Idle) _taskTimer.Change(0, 333);
```

On this base, you can manage your special requirements you were asking for.

Hope this was, what you were searching for.

Comment: Seems a good start, but if im not wrong the queue is a FIFO system so it simply appends the tasks one after an other but doesn't block a lower priority thread when a higher priority thread is called, right?

Comment: I think you can manage it using this system, adding some logical issues.
The alternativ is maybe using the Priority Queue Pattern 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dn589794.aspx

Comment: For my understanding: both methods are not able to block a thread once it's execution has started, right?

Comment: Yes, thats true: They only help you ordering your threads in the right order. To pause a Thread you can use easy meachnism, such as interrupt the Thread and take him to sleep : https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/tttdef8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx    But these are two different issues your facing :)